# Setting up multiple HDD's in HP ProLiant MicroServer G7

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

I have a HP ProLiant MicroServer G7 N54L which came with one 250Gb hdd which I installed Ubuntu on. It also has a 2Tb external USB hdd connected - all this, is working perfectly fine.

When I loaded another SATA hdd into the 2nd bay, it isn't detected in the BIOS or for me to even mount. I can see all sorts of others with similar issues online that all mention smart array and array configuration tools in the boot loader etc etc but I'm unsure where to find any of this.

There doesn't appear to be anything of significance to this in the BIOS. I don't believe the server is faulty as it is aleady working fine with a SATA hdd in the 1st bay (I also tested the other bays the hdd isn't detected in any of them, the hdd also works in another system).

What am I missing? There must be something else required in order to load multiple hdd's into this server?

### Edit

The hdd that I can't get to work in the ProLiant by the way is a:-

- Manufacturer: Western Digital
- Model No: WD10EARS
- Interface: SATA 3Gb/s
- Capacity: 1Tb
- Cache: 64Mb
- Form factor: 3.5 inch

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Perhaps you'd care to read the answer first and my comment to the 'only' answer before commenting with your copy and pasted blanket response @MartinSchröder ...? That way you would see that I did not have to try the suggested answer so cannot confirm whether it would have resolved the problem I was experiencing or not.

Answer (score 2):

I have put in the same server: 1x 3TB WD Red, 2x 2TB Hitachi Deskstar 5K and 1x 1TB Hitachi Deskstar 7K. All 4 disks are detected by the BIOS and I was able to partition and mount them.

So it should work for you too. Because you mentioned that your 1TB HDD is working properly on another machine, I would try to update the BIOS of the Proliant to the latest version available. I would also try to put the working 250GB hdd in the other slots to see if they are not faulty. Finally, you could try to create a new partition table for your 1TB hdd on the machine for which it works, and to select msdos (not GPT) partitioning. Once done, plug back the hdd in the Proliant.

Note: check in your BIOS that you do not have RAID configured and that disks should be using SATA AHCI. I guess this is the case, because you already have 1 disk working, but better double check.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - strangely, I got this working yesterday. I just powered it off, inserted the hdd into bay 2, powered on, went into BIOS and the hdd was detected that time. As far as I can tell/remember, I don't think I did anything different. Perhaps it wasn't completely slotted in before, I don't know. Thanks though for your information.